# Cassandra : Datastax - WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY doesn't work

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I created a table like this:

```
`CREATE TABLE ab(ab_id uuid, login varchar,timestamp varchar, PRIMARY KEY ((ab_id ,login),timestamp)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);`
```

Then I insert data but when I do: `SELECT * FROM ab`
the data is not displayed in the order timestamp

layout:

`07d2a30d-79f3-5619-bbdd-6e5140a68ec3 | testlogin | 2015-04-01 08:48:46 |

 08d3a40c-85c7-5823-ddcc-7e6174d78dg4 | testlogin | 2015-04-01 08:49:07 |

 c35dedeb-3144-5818-c282-53cd7ee1e8e8 | testlogin | 2015-04-01 08:48:58 |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering will only be within the same partition key `(ab_id, login)` in your result set.  Since each `ab_id` in your result set is unique, that is why it is not `timestamp` ordered.